# cytoscape.js arbor layout can not work

Tags: cytoscape.js

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="description" content="[Visual style example]" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Visual style example</title>
  <script src="cytoscape.js-2.0.2/cytoscape.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="cytoscape.js-2.0.2/arbor.js"></script>

<?php
  $fileName=$_GET['fileName'];
  //$fileName="usrID/id_1378400413_14_gene_iterm.txt";
  echo '<script src="data.php?fileName='.$fileName.'"></script>';
?>
  <!--<script src="try.js"></script>-->
  <!--<script src="<?php echo shell_exec('python data.py 2>&1'); ?>"></script>-->

  <script>
    $(function(){
      var cy = $("#cy").cytoscape("get");
      cy.layout({ name: 'random' });
    })
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="cy"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have no problem to use normal, grid, and other layout method, but I don't know why I can not use arbor layout method in my script even I include the arbor.js in a seperated  tag. see   
The arbor.js was download from https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/wiki/Downloads, and put all the scripts in cytoscape.js-2.02 into folder cytoscape. There is no directory path issue.

Anyone who know what's my problem. Is there any more layout method I can use? such as 
Radial
Tree
CompoundSpringEmbedder:
My data is big, I need to find the most suitable layout method, now, it seems normal, grid, breadthfirst not works very well for me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Max Franz's suggestion, I fixed my problem. cy.layout({ name: 'arbor' }) can not be in this html file; layout method 'arbor' must be specified in the init options. Never in ready().